# error en la cuenta

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando una encuesta y a la hora de sumar los votos totales que han realizado me da error.
Este es el código:

```
<?php
    $resultado="";
    if(isset($_COOKIE['voto'])) $voto=$_COOKIE['voto'];
    if(isset($_REQUEST['voteID'])) $voteID=$_REQUEST['voteID'];
    if(isset($_REQUEST['boton_votar'])) $boton_votar=$_REQUEST['boton_votar'];
    if((isset($boton_votar))&&(isset($voteID)) ){
        if((isset($voto))&&($voto=="1")){
            $resultado="<br><font size=3 color=red>Sólo se permite votar una vez!</font><p>";
        }else{
            $id_fichero=fopen("encuesta.txt","r+")or die("<b>No se ha podido abrir el fichero 'encuesta.txt'.</b><p>");
            $votacion=array();
            $titulo_encuesta=trim(fgets($id_fichero,256));
            while(!feof($id_fichero)){
                $linea=fgets($id_fichero,256);
                $votacion[]=explode("¦",$linea);
            }
            fclose($id_fichero);
            $validador=true;
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($voteID);$i++)
                if((!is_numeric($voteID[$i]))&&($voteID>=sizeof($votacion))&&($voteID<0)){
                    $validador=false;
                    break;
                }
            if($validador){
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($voteID);$i++){
                    $votacion[$voteID[$i]][1]+=1;
                }
                $id_fichero=fopen("encuesta.txt","w")or die("<b>No se ha podido crear el fichero 'encuesta.txt'.</b><p>");
                fputs($id_fichero,$titulo_encuesta.chr(13).chr(10));
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($votacion);$i++){
                    $linea=trim(implode("¦",$votacion[$i]));
                    if($i<sizeof($votacion)-1) $linea.= chr(13).chr(10);
                    fputs($id_fichero,$linea);
                }
                fclose($id_fichero);
                setcookie("voto","1",time()+120);
                $resultado="<br><font size=3 color=white>¡Gracias por votar!</font><p>";
            }else $resultado="<br><font size=3 color=red>&iexcl;Opcion de voto incorrecta!</font><p>";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Actividad 2</title>
        <style type=text/css>
            td {font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica}
            body {font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor=91E5F2 text=000000 link=000000 vlink=000000>
        <!-- <center> -->
        <?php echo $resultado; ?>
        <table border=1><tr><td>
            <table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10>
                <tr><td colspan=2 bgcolor=CCCCCC>
                    <font size=3><b>Encuesta</b></td></tr>
                <tr><td bgcolor=FFFFFF><font size=3>
                    <form action="index.php" method="post">
                        <?php
                            $id_fichero=fopen("encuesta.txt","r")or die("<b>El fichero \"encuesta.txt\" no se ha podido abrir.</b><p>");
                            $linea=fgets($id_fichero,256);
                            echo "<br><font size=3><b>$linea</b></font><br>";
                            $i=0;
                            while(!feof($id_fichero)){
                                $linea=fgets($id_fichero,256);
                                $matriz=explode("¦",$linea);
                                echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"voteID[]\" value=\"$i\">".$matriz[0]."<br>";
                                $i++;
                            }
                            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"total_opciones\" value=\"$i\">";
                            fclose($id_fichero);
                        ?>
                        <br><td align=LEFT bgcolor=FFFFFF><input type=submit name="boton_votar" value="Votar"></td>
                    </form>
        <!-- </center> -->
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr></table>
        <p>
        <table cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 width="100%" border=0>
            <tr><td vAlign=top width="100%">
                <!-- <center> -->
                <table cellspacing=2 cellPadding=0 bgColor=#000000 border=0>
                    <tr><td colspan=2 height=50 bgcolor=CCCCCC>
                    <font size=3><b>Resultados</b></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2>
                            <table cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=5 bgColor=#ffffff border=0>
                                <tr><td>
                                <!-- <center> -->
                                <br>
                                    <?php
                                        $id_fichero=fopen("encuesta.txt","r+")or die("<b>No se ha podido abrir el fichero \"encuesta.txt\".</b><p>");
                                        $votacion=array();
                                        $titulo_encuesta=trim(fgets($id_fichero,256));
                                        echo "<b>$titulo_encuesta</b><br>";
                                        $votos_totales=0;
                                        $i=0;
                                        while(!feof($id_fichero)){
                                            $linea=fgets($id_fichero,256);
                                            $votacion[]=explode("¦",$linea);
                                            $votos_totales+=(int)$votacion[$i][1];
                                            $i++;
                                        }
                                        fclose($id_fichero);
                                        echo "<table>";
                                        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($votacion);$i++){
                                            $votacion[$i][1]=trim($votacion[$i][1]);
                                            $porcentaje=number_format($votacion[$i][1]/$votos_totales*100,2);
                                            $long_barra=number_format(128*$votacion[$i][1]/$votos_totales,0);
                                            echo "<tr><td>".$votacion[$i][0]."</td>
                                                <td><img height=14 src=\"images/leftbar.gif\" width=7>";
                                            echo"<img height=14 alt=\"32 %\" src=\"images/mainbar.gif\" width=$long_barra>";
                                            echo "<img height=14 src=\"images/rightbar.gif\" width=7> $porcentaje % (".$votacion[$i][1].")</td></tr>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</table>";
                                    ?>
                                <!-- </center> -->
                                </td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- </center> -->
            </td></tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <center><b><font color=blue>Nº total de votos: <?php echo $votos_totales; ?></font></b></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\Actividad2\index.php on line 102

La línea 102 es esta:

```
$votos_totales+=(int)$votacion[$i][1];
```

Comment: Si le das print_r($votacion[$voteID[$i]]); que te sale?

Comment: $voteID no esta declarado en esa zona del código y me dice que no existe

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado, no era problema del código de esa línea, sino del símbolo que utilizo para separar las dos partes de cada línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en que cuando haces sizeof($voteID), realmente voteID está vacío. De hecho, no es que esté vacío. Está sin definir. Echa un ojo a esta línea:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['voteID'])) $voteID=$_REQUEST['voteID'];
```

Tienes que definir $voteID por fuera y darle el valor que creas necesario.

Comment: Hola Pablo. Gracias por responder pero esta respuesta es solo una linea de codigo y eso es considerado de baja calidad. has de explicar qué problema habia en la pregunta y cómo funciona y cómo soluciona tu codigo su problema. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Pablo, me sale el mismo error poniendo tu línea por la mía

Comment: Editado. La respuesta es totalmente diferente a lo que había puesto anteriormente, echa un ojo.